# loop query even if it finds a match

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have these values:

```
id       info          date
---------------------------------
1        hi            2014-02-15
2        something     2014-10-30
1        hi            2014-12-01
```

As you can see I have two with id #1. If I ask a query to find anything which isn't exported (the date) since 3 months ago. #1 will still go through, even though it was exported first December. Just because it finds the one that was exported 15th February and then it completes the query since it actually finds a match.

How do you do so that the query loops through everything so all matches are taken into consideration?

query i use now (not that it will be much of a help):

```
//------SQL query för att se till att du inte tar ut samma lead igen-----\\
$sql = $pdo->query('SELECT p.* FROM prospects p
LEFT JOIN exported_leads e
on p.id = e.lead_id WHERE p.partner_id != '.$partner_id.' AND (e.lead_id IS NULL OR datediff(now(), e.export_date) > 90)
LIMIT '.$monthly_uttag.'');
//---------------------------------------------\\
```

Comment: Please post the query you are trying to use for this.

Comment: What is your desired output? Why are you not using a primary key?

Comment: posted the query im using now. and @daZza because the table doesnt look like this. multiple people can take out the same one, but it has to be in intervalls of 3 months. which means i have to log the same user for multiple exporters.

Comment: So the `id`column represents a certain person? In that case use a table like `employees` or `customers` or whatever role the people taking out your stuff have and give it a primary key. Use this identifier as a foreign key in the table depicted in your post (instead of id) and add a primary key to it. Then you can select each needed dataset on its own, while keeping the names of your employees/customers/... via a join to the other table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NOT IN` predicate like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT id 
                FROM table1
                WHERE date < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH))
```

This will ignore the `id` 1 since it has a date within the last 2 months interval.

The subquery will get all the ids that has date values within the last 3 months, then the `NOT IN` predicate will ignore these values.

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58b831/3)

Comment: however, if i edit the date of the last one to like in mid june. it still wont find it. but if i change the code to this: WHERE date > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)) it finds both. should it really since only the latest date is the only one that should be taken into consideration?

Comment: @Sharpie it will take all the dates for each id into consideration not the latest date, for example, if an id has 10 date values and only one value has date exceed the 2 months interval the id value will be ingnored. The subquery will get you all the ids that has *at least one date in* the interval 3 months, these lest will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on the layout of your prospects table, but you could join against a sub query to get the latest export_date for each lead_id, and then check just that one in the WHERE clause:-

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM prospects p
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT lead_id, MAX(export_date)
    FROM exported_leads 
    GROUP BY lead_id
)e
on p.id = e.lead_id 
WHERE p.partner_id != '.$partner_id.' 
AND (e.lead_id IS NULL OR datediff(now(), e.export_date) > 90)
LIMIT '.$monthly_uttag.'');
```

Also possible to do this with a normal join, and checking in the having clause. But a bit messier to read! Also you should specify all the fields in the GROUP BY from prospects that you want to return

```
SELECT p.id, partner_id
FROM prospects p
LEFT JOIN exported_leads e
on p.id = e.lead_id 
WHERE p.partner_id != '.$partner_id.' 
GROUP BY p.id, partner_id
HAVING (e.lead_id IS NULL OR datediff(now(), MAX(e.export_date) > 90))
LIMIT '.$monthly_uttag.'');
```

Comment: these sound interesting. ill try them when i get home and have time and get back to you how it worked out